# Solve for $n$, where $n$ is a positive integer

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I have

$$ {n \choose 2} = 21 $$

and as the title mentions I have to solve for $n$, but so far all I have managed to get to is

$$n^2 -n =42 $$

and from there I'm completely lost. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square

Comment: Life, the universe, and everything: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#42_Puzzle

Comment: By observation, $42=(7)(6)=(-6)(-7)$ so the quadratic equation $42=(n)(n-1)$ has solutions $7$ and $-6$.

Comment: Why is this tagged ([tag:probability])?

Comment: @MPW: $n$ is a positive integer

Comment: Yes, that's the next step--take the solutions to the quadratic and see which one(s) satisfy the original question. So you would eliminate one of the solutions to the quadratic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $$n^2-n=42\iff n^2-n-42=0\iff (n-7)(n+6)=0$$
and that $n\ge 2$.

Comment: I think my brain has left for a holiday at this point. I can't believe i didn't see this before. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Paul: You are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Hint : $n^2 - n - 42 = (n-7)(n+6)$

Answer (score 1):

$$n^2-n=(n-1)n.$$
You need to find two consecutive integers with product $42$.

Check among $2,6,12,20,30,42,56,72,90...$.

Hint: the nearest perfect squares are $6^2=36$ and $7^2=49$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, if you know the formula for the sum of the first $n-1$ integers, which is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=\binom{n}{2}
$$
We can check at each step until: $1+2+3+4+5+6=21$, and we get $n=7$.

Comment: Dear Teacher, If ı ask you, can you look my problem, if you have few minutes? Is it possible?  I need a mathematician's answer. Best Regards. Thank you so much.    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559814/is-the-proof-i-am-using-sufficient-correct-for-the-system-of-equation